# How can you print integers from a class

Tags: c++, class, numbers

This seems like a simple thing to me, but I have an entity class:

```
class Entity
{
private:
    std::string m_Name;
public:
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    Entity() : m_Name("Undefined Entity") {
        std::cout << m_Name << " Created!\n";
    }
    Entity(const std::string& name) : m_Name(name) {
        std::cout << m_Name << " Created!\n";
    }

    ~Entity() {
        std::cout << m_Name << " Destroid\n";
    }

    const std::string GetName() { return m_Name; }

    void PrintCords() { std::cout << x << ' , ' << y << '\n'; }
};
```

and in my main function I run the PrintCords function:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> j = std::make_unique<Entity>("Jeff");
    std::cout << j->GetName() << '\n';
    j->PrintCords();
}
```

Yet, when I run the program, I get seemingly random numbers:
`021084480`

Comment: This has nothing to do with printing integers from a class. If you turn on your compiler's warnings, your compiler will tell you what the problem is. If your compiler is not saying anything, perhaps you might want to consider upgrading your compiler.  `' , '` is not, I repeat, this is not a literal string consisting of a space, a command, and another space. VTC as a typo.

Comment: Typo - `' , '` should be `" , "`.  Your compiler can warn you about such typos if you enable warnings (well, maybe expect MSVC): https://godbolt.org/z/1P5E3nx3x

Answer (score 0):

You should compile with `-Werror`. This turns your warnings into errors. When you do this, you will see the following error:

> prog.cpp:25:43: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
> void PrintCords() { std::cout << x << ' , ' << y << '\n'; }
> ^~~~~

Which should indicate to you that something is wrong. If you change this to a string literal:

```
void PrintCords() { std::cout << x << " , " << y << '\n'; }
                                 ---> ^   ^
```

[Then everything will be ok.](https://ideone.com/BfAmuk)

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see that there were spaces, so I though it was a char!